# ¿copia valores almacenados en una pila a un vector usando la libreria STL en c++?

Tags: c++

existe alguna forma de copiar valores almacenados en una pila hacia un vector utilizando la libreria STL por ejemplo

```
stack<int> v1 = { 5, 7, 9};
```

de ahi copiar lo que tengo almacenado en la pila hacia un vector

```
vector<int> v2(v1);
```

esto es lo que quisiera hacer pero por lo que he leido la pila no contiene un iterador

Answer (score 4):

La pila `std::stack` contiene un miembro protegido que es el contenedor subyacente de la misma. Si puedes acceder a dicho contenedor subyacente, podrás iterarlo; para eso usa una clase ayudante:

```
template <typename T>
struct ayudante : std::stack<T>
{
    using pila = std::stack<T>;
    using contenedor_subyacente = pila::container_type;

    ayudante(const pila &p) : contenedor{p.*&ayudante::c} {}

    auto begin() { return contenedor.begin(); }
    auto end() { return contenedor.end(); }

private:
    const contenedor_subyacente &contenedor;
};
```

Una vez puedes iterar la pila, copiar su contenido es trivial:

```
std::stack<int> s;
s.push(1);
s.push(2);
s.push(3);

auto a = ayudante{s};
std::vector<int> v;
v.reserve(s.size());
std::copy(a.begin(), a.end(), std::back_inserter(v));

for (const auto &valor : v)
    std::cout << valor << ' ';
```

El código anterior muestra:

> ```
> 1 2 3
> ```

Ten en cuenta que he definido la clase `ayudante` para que use la pila pasada por referencia como sólo lectura.

Comment: a ok entonces con esa clase ya definida con su iterador subyacente ya puedo realizar varias manipulaciones como si fuera un vector etc muchas gracias por la info

Answer (score 3):

Según el estándar, `std::stack< >` ha de tener, como mínimo:

```
template< class T, class Container = deque< T > > class stack {
public:
  typedef typename Container::value_type value_type;
  typedef typename Container::size_type size_type;
  typedef          Container container_type;

protected:
  Container c;

...
```

El elemento clave aquí es el último: `Container c;`. Esa variable-miembro nos da acceso a la instancia del contenedor usado por la `std::stack< >`.
El *problema* es que está definida como `protected`, por lo que no tenemos mas remedio que utilizar una clase auxiliar para conseguir acceder a él:

```
template< typename T > typename T::container_type &subyacent_container( T &stack ) {
  struct Aux : public T {
    using T::c;
  };

  return static_cast< Aux & >( stack ).c;
}
```

En C++11, podemos sobrecargar tanto `std::begin( )` y `std::end( )` para que use nuestra nueva función `subyacent_container< >( )`, lo cual nos permitirá integrar `std::stack< >` con otras partes de la librería estandar:

```
namespace std {

template< typename T > typename T::container_type::iterator begin( T &o ) { return subyacent_container( o ).begin( ); }

template< typename T > typename T::container_type::iterator end( T &o ) { return subyacent_container( o ).end( ); }

}
```

Un ejemplo totalmente funcional, que puedes comprobar [<kbd>aquí</kbd>](https://wandbox.org/permlink/vo6FH2tab4ddh2ka):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>

template< typename T > typename T::container_type &subyacent_container( T &stack ) {
  struct Aux : public T {
    using T::c;
  };

  return static_cast< Aux & >( stack ).c;
}

namespace std {

template< typename T > typename T::container_type::iterator begin( T &o ) { return subyacent_container( o ).begin( ); }

template< typename T > typename T::container_type::iterator end( T &o ) { return subyacent_container( o ).end( ); }

}

int main( ) {
  std::stack< int > stack;

  stack.push( 1 );
  stack.push( 2 );
  stack.push( 3 );

  std::vector< int > vector( begin( stack ), end( stack ) );

  std::cout << "Contenido de 'vector':\n";    
  for( auto iter: vector ) std::cout << iter << ' ';

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias por la info y la ayuda

Answer (score 2):

Para conseguir tu propósito no queda más remedio que *hackear* la clase `std::stack`. Si bien no parece muy conveniente saltarse la encapsulación de una clase, en este caso es relativamente sencillo conseguir iterar por una pila.

`std::stack` no es mas que un adaptador montado sobre otro contenedor. El contenedor de base debe garantizar la adyacencia de los datos. Con esta información en mente es relativamente sencillo montar un sistema de iteradores:

```
template<class T>
class StackIterator
{
public:
  StackIterator(T* ptr)
    : ptr{ptr}
  { }

  T & operator*()
  { return *ptr; }

  StackIterator& operator++()
  {
    ++ptr;
    return *this;
  }

  StackIterator operator++(int)
  { return {++ptr}; }

  bool operator==(StackIterator const& other) const
  { return ptr == other.ptr; }

  bool operator!=(StackIterator const& other) const
  { return ptr != other.ptr; }

private:

   T* ptr;
};
```

El iterador en si es bastante simple. Itera por las posiciones de memoria del contenedor interno del la clase `stack`.

Para que este iterador *se enganche* con la STL es necesario añadir algo de información al espacio de nombres `std`:

```
namespace std {
  template<class T>
  struct iterator_traits<StackIterator<T>>
  {
    using value_type = T;
    using iterator_category = forward_iterator_tag;
  };

  template<class T>
  StackIterator<T> begin( std::stack<T> &o )
  { return {&o.top() - o.size() + 1}; }

  template<class T>
  StackIterator<T> end( std::stack<T> &o )
  { return {&o.top() + 1}; } // +1 para leer el ultimo elemento de la pila
}
```

Lo primero es una clase auxiliar que proporciona información sobre el contenedor. Esta clase es utilizada a nivel interno por la STL. A continuación se encuentran las especializaciones de las funciones `std::begin` y `std::end`.

El funcionamiento del código se puede verificar con un ejemplo sencillo:

```
int main()
{
  std::stack<int> stack;
  stack.push(1);
  stack.push(2);
  stack.push(3);
  stack.push(4);

  std::vector<int> vector;

  std::copy(std::begin(stack), std::end(stack), std::back_inserter(vector));

  for( auto item : vector )
  { std::cout << item << ' '; }
}
```

Siendo la salida del programa:

```
1 2 3 4
```

Si quisiésemos hacer la iteración en el sentido natural de la pila, es decir, del último elemento al primero, deberíamos modificar `StackIterator` y los métodos `std::begin` y `std::end`:

```
template<class T>
class StackIterator
{
  StackIterator& operator++()
  {
    --ptr;
    return *this;
  }

  StackIterator operator++(int)
  { return {--ptr}; }
};

namespace std {
  template<class T>
  StackIterator<T> begin( std::stack<T> &o )
  { return {&o.top()}; }

  template<class T>
  StackIterator<T> end( std::stack<T> &o )
  { return {&o.top() - o.size()}; }
}
```

Con estos cambios conseguimos que la salida del programa sea

```
4 3 2 1
```

Comment: Me he asustado al leer la primera línea: `Si bien no parece muy conveniente saltarse la encapsulación de una clase, ...`, que conste :-)

Comment: @Trauma jajajajaja. El comentario no iba por tu respuesta sino por la mia. Diseñar un sistema que se salte la encapsulación tiene sus riesgos y está bien indicarlos :)

Comment: muchas gracias por la ayuda algo nuevo aprendido gracias